# List gets cut when using justify-content: center

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items which needs to be aligned center for which I used 'Justify-content: center'. But this leads to the start of content to be cut. When I change the center to 'flex-start' it works but the list is not centered if list items are less.

```css
.editorial-grid__first-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: scroll;
  /* background-color: $editorial-gray-3; */
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.editorial-grid__first-item {
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: $white; */
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<ul class="edit-grid__first-list">
  <li class="edit-grid__first-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span> First item </span>
  </li>
  <li class="edit-grid__second-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span> second item </span>
  </li>
  <li class="edit-grid__third-item">
    <a href="#">
      <span> third item </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code is not sufficient to understand what's your problem.

Comment: Please fix your example first of all. Currently, the classes in the CSS selectors don’t match the classes used in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the list in a `div` and center it. You can do it like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.editorial-grid__first-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: $editorial-gray-3;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.editorial-grid__first-item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: $white;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="edit-grid__first-list">
    <li class="edit-grid__first-item">
      <a href="#">
        <span> First item </span>
    </li>
    <li class="edit-grid__second-item">
      <a href="#">
        <span> second item </span>
    </li>
    <li class="edit-grid__third-item">
      <a href="#">
        <span> third item </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```